# Using OTB-Wrapping of Orfeo Toolbox (Java)?

Tags: java, orfeo-toolbox

I can not find the code/binding/whatever for Java...

http://orfeo-toolbox.org/otb/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orfeo_toolbox

Can someone help me on that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately since last OTB release 4.X, the OTB-Wrapping is not maintained. We could not find time/resources for now to migrate this project.

There is lots of work to do this to migrate the backend of the project to the new wrapping framework of ITK and work to migrate after OTB filters.

There is a way to use OTB from Java by using the SWIG interface of tyhe OTB applications (utilities). You can have a look at the doc in the cookbook:

http://orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBookch1.html#x6-50001